# Erro ao usar doctrine instalado via composer

Tags: php, doctrine, composer

Instalei o Doctrine via composer:

```
{
  "require": {
      "doctrine/common": "2.4.*",
      "doctrine/dbal": "2.4.*",
      "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*",
      "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
  }
}
```

Ao executar os testes unitários, a localização do arquivo `ArrayCollection` não foi encontrada pelo *namespace*.

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Erro apresentado:

> Fatal error:  Class 'DoctrineNaPratica\Model\ArrayCollection' not found in /Users/israel/Sites/doctrine/src/DoctrineNaPratica/Model/User.php on line 183
>
> Fatal error: Class 'DoctrineNaPratica\Model\ArrayCollection' not found in /Users/israel/Sites/doctrine/src/DoctrineNaPratica/Model/User.php on line 183

Essa linha 183 tem o seguinte código:

```
public function __construct() 
{            
    $this->courseCollection = new ArrayCollection;
    $this->lessonCollection = new ArrayCollection;
    $this->profileCollection = new ArrayCollection;
    $this->enrollmentCollection = new ArrayCollection;
}
```

E a Collection é declarada via *annotations*:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Course", mappedBy="teacher", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true, fetch="LAZY")
 * 
 * @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection   
 */
 protected $courseCollection;
```

Creio que o problema está relacionado a estrutura de pasta gerado pelo composer.

A estrutura de pasta que o composer montou para o doctrine está errada?
Como fazer para corrigir?

Disponibilizei o código no [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/israeleduardo/doctrine-na-pratica.git).

Estou usando php 5.4.30.

Comment: Eu copiei teu composer.json e instalei os pacotes aqui, não houve nenhum erro ao executar o comando phpunit. Tenta apagar a pasta vendor e o arquivo composer.lock e manda instalar de novo.

Comment: tenta baixar a git que compartilhei. Ao executar suas orientacoes, apareceu o mesmo erro. O problema ocorre na classe USER qd tenta instanciar um arraycollecction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa usar o nome completo da classe, ou seja, o FQCN (*fully classified class name*) dela, se quiser usá-la.

Se você não fizer isso, o PHP vai achar que você está tentando carregar a classe no mesmo namespace em que o arquivo atual se encontra (ou seja, `DoctrineNaPratica\Model`)

Pode-se fazê-lo de duas maneiras:

Importar a classe no bloco `use`, logo após a declaração `namespace`, da sua classe:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
```

... ou apontar o FQCN da classe quando instanciá-la ou quando chamar um método estático dela:

```
$this->courseCollection     = new Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
$this->lessonCollection     = new Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
$this->profileCollection    = new Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
$this->enrollmentCollection = new Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
```